# How to detect type of selected printer that is dot matrix or not?

Tags: c#, winapi, printing, dot-matrix

Normally, in old version Windows (98 or older) I can use MarkingTechnology in Printer api to get current type of printer. But it doesn't available in Windows 2000 or later. Do you have any other way to detect it in Windows 2000 or later?

**Example code for query printer information via WMI Query in C#**

```
var queryResult = string.Empty;
var query = new WqlObjectQuery("Select * from Win32_Printer");
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);

foreach (ManagementObject printer in searcher.Get())
{
    foreach (var p in printer.Properties)
    {
        queryResult += p.Name + ": " + printer[p.Name] + Environment.NewLine;
    }

    queryResult += "--------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

[Win32_Printer class documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394363%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

**Thanks,**

Comment: I think we can detect it via Horizontal Resolution that my test dot matrix printer is 120 DPI instead of at least 300 DPI in normal printer.

Comment: However, it still has some printer that resolution is higher than 300DPI.

http://www.equanet.co.uk/catalogue/item/Y871451

Comment: Is there a laser out there with a resolution of 360dpi?  My experience is that lasers use 300dpi or multiples thereof.  The problem is low-range inkjets (which could be 360dpi/b&W) and some oddballs such as my label printer: http://www.brother-usa.com/PTouch/ModelDetail.aspx?ProductID=PT1500PC which is 180dpi/b&w (but which can be distinguished by examining the paper available.)

Comment: Resolution isn't a good way to distinguish.  I've seen dot matrix printers with a resolution as high as 144 dpi in at least one dimension.  If you do rely on resolution, you might want to check for very low resolutions, in order to rule out daisy wheel style printers.

Comment: Why do you need to know if it's dot-matrix?  Perhaps there's another way to solve your problem if we know the motivation.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy In this situation, I try to print some paper out. Normally, we need to use different kind of code to print data between normal printer and dot-matrix printer that is the reason why I need auto-detect at the time. However, I don't work for that project anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No, there does not seem to be a consistent way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I do my best to find out the possible way to detect Dot Matrix printer. I try to call GetDeviceCaps function (retrieves device-specific information for the specified device.) to get **TECHNOLOGY** item that should return as **Character stream** if selected printer is Dot Matrix.

```
var hdc = CreateDC("WINSPOOL", printerName, null, IntPtr.Zero);
var technology = (DeviceCapTechnology)GetDeviceCaps(hdc, (int)DeviceCap.TECHNOLOGY);
```

However, it always return TECHNOLOGY item as **Raster display**. I don't know why it always return value like this.

```
[DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
static extern int GetDeviceCaps(IntPtr hdc, int nIndex);

[DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr CreateDC(string lpszDriver, string lpszDevice, string lpszOutput, IntPtr lpInitData);
```

[GetDeviceCaps function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144877%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[Example Project](https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=f093f24662880947&resid=F093F24662880947!2399&parid=F093F24662880947!2400)